# PSN store purchased games from the past

Tags: ps3, psn

If I have purchased games on the ps3 network store on my old ps3, how do I access them on my new ps3?

Comment: I can see them when I'm logged in on my laptop, just not where to find them when I'm logged in on the ps3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your PSN purchases are tied to your PSN account.

By simply logging into your old PSN account on your new console, you should be able to access your past purchases.

Comment: I should point out however there is a limited number of activations for content from the store before you will need to purchase it again, activations are the number of consoles that the content has been actived for, this is different from the number of registered PS3 Consoles you have tied to your PSN Account since you can registered a console tied to your PSN Account, this way a user can't just buy a crap ton of games, activate and deactivate consoles and hand out all those games for free and thus allow people to essentially pirate the games

Comment: re downloading the same content on the same console multiple times does reduce the number of activations as i have re downloaded the Mugen Souls DLC ~10 times finding out which DLC was not OPed, the number activations is reduced only 1, the message about "Activating" when you download is just the check

Answer (score 2):

You just have to log in with your Playstation-Network-Account and then you have acces on everything you purchased on your old PS3.

Just search for the game or whatever you want (in your PSN Store) to download and there you will see that its already purchased and downloadable.

Comment: ok cool. cheers

Comment: Another fast way to do it is to go to PSN Account Settings on the XMB (main system interface) and go to Download List under your account information--then you can go through everything you've ever bought without having to go to the store app.